# How to change variable value based on condition

Tags: c#, variables

In the event the `firstvariable == "1"`, and `secondvariable == "example"`, I want to change the value of `firstvariable` to `== "0"`, else `firstvariable` stays `== "1"`

In below code, I've commented out what I essentially want to happen but don't know what to put in the `else` line to make it happen.

```
if (InvPriorityCode == "1") 
{
    if (InvCustEmail != "")
    {
        return "EMAIL";
    }
    else 
    //set InvPriorityCode == "0"
}
```

Comment: `InvPriorityCode = "0"`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. There is no `set` keyword in C#.

Comment: Please get a book or follow a tutorial; C# is too complicated to guess the syntax.

Comment: It also seems like you could have picked just about any existing random post here and seen how it is done.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to answer your question because your pseudo code does not match your description above it very closely.

To simply do what you mentioned in the comment line:

```
// Set InvPriorityCode to "0"
InvPriorityCode = "0";
```

However, your pseudo code does not seem sufficient to do what you said in your initial description.

I think that the following would get you close, but you should read it and tell me if I've misunderstood what you need it to do.

```
if (InvPriorityCode == "1")
{
    if (InvCustEmail == "example")
    {
        InvPriorityCode = "0";
    }
}
```

You can also simplify your code by combining the two `if` statements to `if (InvPriorityCode == "1" && InvCustEmail == "example")`.

However, this leaves out your line `return "EMAIL"`... what were you trying to do there? Do you want that to happen when `InvCustEmail == "example"`? If so, it should be in the same `if` with setting `InvPriorityCode = "0"`, and not the opposite case as you did in your pseudo code.

Answer (score 3):

Solely going by your description at the beginning, it looks like this is what you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firstVariable = "1";
    var secondVariable = "example";

    if (firstVariable == "1" && secondVariable == "example")
    {
        firstVariable = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        firstVariable = "1";
    }
}
```

If `firstVariable` is `1` AS WELL AS `secondVariable` is `example`, then you'd change the value of `firstVariable` to zero. Else, to `1`.

But it appears that you are struggling with syntax here.

In C# (and most other languages), the assignment (setting, as you call it, a value to a variable) is done by the assignment operator, which is a single `=`.

The two equal signs `==` is reserved for comparison.